# Scaffold-DbContext ignores table after updating to EF Core tools 6.0.5

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, scaffolding, ef-core-6.0

After updating from EF Core Tools 5 to EF Core tools (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools) 6.0.5 I noticed that when running `Scaffold-DbContext`, a table in the database is completely ignored and no class for it is being generated. The database structure is rather complex so I don't know what exactly causes this problem but the class which was generated in previous versions of the EF Core tools looked like this:

```
public partial class TableName
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual RelatedTable1 Related1 { get; set; }
    public virtual RelatedTable2 Related2 { get; set; }
}
```

When inspecting the generated code in `OnModelCreating`, I found out that the tools are in fact aware of the existence of this table. For example, in the `modelBuilder` code for another table which is related to the missing table, a `UsingEntity` call like this is being added:

```
entity.HasMany(d => d.Types)
    .WithMany(p => p.Related1)
    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
        "TableName",
        l => l.HasOne<RelatedTable2>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("TypeId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull).HasConstraintName("TBL_..."),
        r => r.HasOne<RelatedTable1>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("Id").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull).HasConstraintName("TBL_..."),
        j =>
        {
            j.HasKey("Id", "TypeId");
    
            j.ToTable("...");
    
            j.HasIndex(new[] { "TypeId" }, "IX_T..._type_ID");
    
            j.IndexerProperty<string>("Id").HasMaxLength(50).HasColumnName("id");
    
            j.IndexerProperty<int>("TypeId").HasColumnName("type_ID");
        });
```

Why does it decide to do this instead of generating a class for this table? Did anyone experience similar problems like this and has an idea what causes this problem and what can be done about it?

UPDATE:
After looking through the breaking changes in EF Core 6, I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes#many-to-many) change which might be exactly what causes this problem in my project. However, I don't yet fully understand how I am supposed to update my code so I don't have to downgrade again or add any additional steps to do every time I run `Scaffold-DbContext` again.

Comment: This is due to many to many tables support in scaffolding. You can disable in EF Core Power Tools to get previous model generated.

Comment: Reading the documentation, it suggests this behavior only applies when the join table doesn't have any additional attributes, just the 2 FK's. Maybe if you add an attribute to the join entity, EF reverts to the old behavior?

Comment: @ErikEJ Could you explain where exactly this can be disabled in EF Core Power Tools?

Comment: @pjs Probably, but this just does not seem like a good solution to me. Unless there is an option to revert to the old behavior, I'd prefer to adapt my application code to whatever Microsoft thinks would be the "correct" way to handle this. Unfortunately, I do not really understand what Microsoft expects a developer to do here.

Comment: @Chris You can disable the may to many mapping and just have the proper entity M2M entity generated

Comment: @ErikEJ Yes, but where can I disable this? Is it an additional option when calling `Scaffold-DbContext`, or where can this be disabled?

Comment: It is a feature in EF Core Power Tools